# jquery convert seconds into this format

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer

Hi i have installed a plugin in that there is a countdown timer is there:

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
 var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }
      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }

    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) +  1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

i have a countdown timer code which runs based on seconds..

So i want to write my code which is in seconds to  **deadline**  from above code format.

```
var gdtesttime  = 00:15:00;         //hh:mm:ss
var a = gdtesttime.split(':');      // split it at the colons
var gdseconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 ;  //seconds
```

I need help in these 2 major lines:

**1.**`var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) +  1 * 60 * 60 * 1000);`

**2.**`var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());`

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="clockdiv" class="pull-right">
    <span><img src="assets/images/timer.png" /></span>
    <div class="disp-none">
        <span class="days"></span>
        <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="hours"></span><span>:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="minutes"></span><span>:</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="seconds"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/k4b81x8c/

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: Its good you can create with JSFiddle

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k4b81x8c/ here is fiddle for the count down timer @MuhammadAkberKhan

Comment: Did you guys understood my question..? with this fiddle, i want to send one parameter that is in seconds and it should start countdown.

Comment: What is endtime ?  Is that Unix seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in js if you add `var gdtesttime  = 00:15:00;` you have to give this time in `"` or `'` quotes. also apply * 1000 while you are converting `gdseconds` and finally add it to dead line. So update your script to :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
 var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }
      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }
    var gdtesttime  = "00:15:00";         //hh:mm:ss
    var a = gdtesttime.split(':');      // split it at the colons
    var gdseconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 * 1000;  //miliseconds
    var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + gdseconds);
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
</script>
```

check js fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/k4b81x8c/1/

Comment: i want to call a function the timer becomes to zero where can i write that.? @b-desai